# How to use MSSQL Select in Groovy

Tags: sql-server, groovy, soapui

I'm trying to access the table from a database.  First I checked the connection of the database and it worked. Then I checked the close db and it worked.  After I try to select couple of items from the table and print them using eachraw command.

I'm getting below error:

```
Wed Oct 05 07:26:01 EDT 2016:INFO:No signature of method: groovy.sql.Sql.eachrow() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, Script26$_run_closure1) values: [SELECT Type,Description FROM A.dbo.Type, ...]
Possible solutions: eachRow(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure), eachRow(groovy.lang.GString, groovy.lang.Closure), eachRow(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure, groovy.lang.Closure), eachRow(java.lang.String, java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure), eachRow(java.lang.String, java.util.Map, groovy.lang.Closure), eachRow(java.util.Map, java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure)
```

This is my code:

```
    import groovy.sql.Sql


    try{

    def dbURL="jdbc:sqlserver://1.1.2.1:1433;databaseName=A"
    def dbUsername="sa"
    def dbPassword="password"
    def dbDriver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

    def db = Sql.newInstance(dbURL,dbUsername,dbPassword,dbDriver)

    def q1 = "SELECT Type,Description FROM A.dbo.Type"


    db.eachrow(q1){row ->
       log.info "${it.toString().Description}"
    }



   }catch (Exception e){
       log.info "Some db error"
       log.info e.getMessage()

   }finally{

   db.close()

   }
```

Comment: Thanks @Rao for the update.

Comment: `eachrow` is case sensitive and you have it lower case. Can you please check with `eachRow` instead?

Comment: I checked it. Now I'm getting 'No such property: it for class: Script30'

Comment: Also, I have to comment out the db.close() otherwise it is giving the error (Not exception)

Comment: Define `db` before `try` block.

Comment: toString() seems be wrong

Comment: I tried that. Giving same error @Rao.

Comment: @Jace Cz  in the beginning tried it without the toString() and it gave some error. so someone suggest to put it. So I put it there. I removed/ inserting didn't change the exception throw message

Comment: Did You try?  db.eachrow(q1){row ->
       log.info row.Description
    }  because in loop lambda expresssion 'it' is absent. Probably was copied from wrong example

Comment: @user3174886 I'm sure String.Description hasn't sense

Comment: it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @JacekCz when do we use it then? I was following a tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method is eachRow, no eachrow, and if you specify a row variable name inside the closure, you have to use 'row' instead of 'it'.
So you code should look like this:

```
db.eachRow(q1){row ->
       log.info "${row.description}"
}
```